# Desktop PC restarting without any indication

Tags: windows, reboot

My desktop PC having windows 7 operating system installed is restarting without any indication. But when I boot into safe-mode it's working fine. I have checked each and every component with substitute excluding motherboard and processor, still the problems exists.
What might be the cause of restarting and not in safe-mode.

Comment: I've usually found that if I've gone to the lengths you have described, its a bad motherboard. Safemode doesn't load many of your drivers and services, so the load on the system is much lighter, and many of the more complicated functions of the board are not used. That's why its safe mode.

Comment: I used to have the same problem. @FrankThomas is right about resource usage. Please buy some thermal paste and apply it on processor, right below the cooling fan. This may be helpful: https://www.pcgamer.com/how-to-properly-apply-thermal-paste-and-install-a-cpu/

Answer (score 0):

try running the windows sys diagnostics and see what you get out of that, it also could be your OS is corrupted or being manually controlled through another computer(not likely though).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a fresh install of Windows, to clear up any additional factors that might be causing the problem. Another question is how are the thermals on the PC? Sometimes this may be a contributing factor to the shut-off problem as well, I've had this happen when I was testing the limits of my rig, overclocking and such.

Comment: I do a fresh installation of windows and now it is working fine. I have  two harddisk, one is loaded with windows 7 which is fine after fresh installation and other is loaded with ubuntu 15.10 which is getting restarting when the Ubuntu desktop comes. Any solution would be helpful.